# Is it possible to use WAMP on multiple ports?

Tags: apache, routes, wamp, wampserver

I would like to be able to run WAMP simultaneously on ports 80 and 8080. Is this possible?

I would like to be able to view my virtual hosts normally like http://site1.localhost on port 80 but also use DDNS services that point to my server and open my router and firewall on port 8080 to allow customers to see their beta site at, say, http://whatever.dlinkddns.com:8080.

Right now, it works locally for me. I can go to http://site1.localhost and http://site2.localhost:8080. I can also go to http://192.168.1.100:8080 successfully. But when I try view the site from the outside (WAN) I get a connection timed out.

I use WAMP 3.1 and dlinkddns.com for DDNS.

Comment: DDNS normally forward to port 80 only

Comment: It is simpler to have everything runing on port 80. Just amend your Virtual Host definition for one specific site you are demoing from `Require local` to `Require all granted` for the duration of the demo

Comment: Oh and make sure ALL your Virtual Hosts are only `Require local` normally so your other sites dont get hacked on

Comment: Oh even better, if you know the clients WAN IP address you can amend the VH to `Require ip 99.99.99.99` and only they will be allowed in

Comment: I know it's simpler to run everything on port 80 and I can do that. I just want to know if it's possible to run on port 80 locally but 8080 on the WAN. I'm running another application that responds to my DDNS address on port 80, so I would like to redirect Web requests to port 8080.

Comment: If the `ServerName` of each Virtual Host is different (as of course it should be) then you can run any number of Virtually Hosted sites on port 80. Thats the prime function of a Virtual Host. Apache looks at the incoming URL and then searches the VH Domain list so it can launch the correct site. _How do you think Hosting Companies run a 1000 sites on a single Shared Hosting Server on one machine and using one instance of Apache_

Comment: I know that. I run 50+ sites on WAMP localhost. It's a Web appliance that is accessible via the WAN that runs on port 80 and it doesn't use Apache. It uses its own built-in Web server. I run on port 80 locally but on WAN I would need to use port 8080. That's why I need to run two ports simultaneously, because port 80 on WAN is being used.

Comment: One option would have been to make your router port forward port 80 incoming traffic to port 8080 on your Apache machine, but as you already have one DDNS site using port 80 you cannot do that or the other site would stop working

Comment: Yea, that would cause the Web appliance not to run because it will only respond on port 80.

Comment: Which DDNS are you using

Comment: And what version of WAMPServer

Comment: Will that let you forward to a non port 80

Comment: DDNS doesn't care what port it is. It just resolves an hostname to an IP address. All the forwarding is done at my router.

Comment: `dlinkddns.com` is DNYDNS.com [Read this article](https://help.dyn.com/standard-dns/webhops-and-redirects-in-standard-dns/), section called **Redirecting to an Alternate Port**

Comment: Then upgrade to [`WAMPServer 3.1.1`](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Then right click on `wampmanager icon->Tools->Add a Listen port for apache` You need to upgrade to `3.1.1` as there is a fix in that for this process. The upgade to `3.1.1` will not effect anything in Apache/MySQL/PHP etc It only effects WAMPServers control code

Comment: Turns out it was a Windows Firewall issue. After checking System and Security -> Windows Defender Firewall -> Allowed Apps, I noticed I hadn't allowed Apache on the Public side. It was allowed on the Private side but I had to open Publicly.

I did upgrade to WAMP 3.1.1 so that piece of advice was helpful. That upgrade isn't mentioned on their main Web site.